# Run script when network connection is up

Tags: networking, systemd

I'm running a set of Debian Jessie based servers and need a reliable way to upload their local network IP Address when the network link is established.
I wrote a script that does this and registered it as a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Server Registration
Requires=network.target network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=<script-location>
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
WatchdogSec=21600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Alas, if this were working as expected it wouldn't be a question on SO. The script makes use of the `route` command to determine the network device used by default, but fails to run because route exits due to the network not being up yet. Also, the system may boot up without a network connection and only be connected later, so the script needs to be triggered anytime the network goes up.

Network is set up using systemd-networkd.

How can i ensure that my script is run whenever the network goes up, and not before?

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify both `network.target` and `network-online.target`? The systemd [wiki page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) says you need to add dependency on the `network-online.target` and does not mention `network.target`.

Comment: network.target happens before network-online.target. I don't necessarily need to use it, that's true.

Comment: If it does not fix it, then there is workaround - modify your script to properly handle "no network" situation and wait until network goes up.

Comment: So I actually needed to enable `network-online.target` for it to be available, bu this then interrupts the boot process until a network connection is available, which is a no-go

Comment: Yes, the docs say that the boot will be delayed until network becomes available. I would modify the script to check for network availability in the loop like `while(!network_available){sleep 1}` (pseudo code). In this way your script will proceed only after network is up.